# Galois theory ( 5 degree polynomial)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $G$ is the Galois group of an irreducible degree 5 polynomial $f\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $|G|=10$. Then $f$ must have precisely 1 or 5 real roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the only options are 1,3 or 5 different real options, as complex roots of real polynomials appear in conjugate pairs and *there is at least* 1 real root (why?) , so we have to rule the possibility of three real roots and a conjugate pair of complex non-real ones.

But then embedding $\,G\,$ in $\,S_5\,$ we'd get it contains a $\,5-\,$ cycle (as $\,G\,$ has a sbgp. of order 5) but *also* a transposition (as the complex roots must be
mapped to themselves) , and $\,S_5\,$ is generated by any $\,5-\,$ cycle and any transposition...